# Why have I randomly lost two upvotes on an answer?

Tags: support, voting, up-votes

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8768638/840973) which I wrote on Jan 7 has been my most upvoted answer up till now.

Last night when I was looking at my profile, it still had 7 upvotes, but this morning it only has 5.

How can this have happened, when it hasn't been downvoted (check the vote count), and I last edited it 15 minutes after posting it?

I'm not too worried about the votes, but just interested as to why that happened?

Comment: timeline shows only 5 upvotes for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8768627/timeline

Comment: @gnat - if the users were destroyed then it would be as if the user never existed and hence those votes would have never existed.

Comment: Oh well, I +1'd, so now you only need +1 more :P.

Comment: @gnat I guarantee I had 7 upvotes - tried to look on Google Cache but doesn't have a recent enough snapshot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can think of a couple of cases:

1. The users who provided those two up-votes are destroyed - all posts are deleted and all votes removed.
2. The users were sock puppets of another user that also voted for that answer - so you ended up with 3 votes from the same person or 2 votes from 2 people. If the socks were discovered and merged then the duplicate votes will be removed.